# application cache with page cache in php?

Tags: php, caching

Do we get any undesired results when we use application cache in combination with page cache in php?

Thanks & Regards,
Satya

Comment: Can you define these concepts better in relation to your application? By themselves they don't mean very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple layers of caching is often a good idea.

I'm going to assume that:

- "application cache" means a key-value cache like Memcached or Xcache
- "page cache" means caching the entire page output, via PHP or in an HTTP proxy.

In this case, it's a great idea to use the two together.  The "page cache" is a course-grained cache that will frequently miss, but cache hits will have little to no work to do.  The "application cache" is more fine grained and will more frequently hit, but some work is still required to assemble this into a full page.

I hope this comes close to what you were asking.